# Android fragment lifecycle issue

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I instantiate my Fragments in the **onCreate()** of my first activity. In this case in can see the following application flow :

- MainActivity : onCreate()
- Fragment1 : onAttach() : where I get a listener to get data from the Activity
- Fragment1 : onCreateView()
- Fragment2 : onAttach()
- Fragment2 : onCreateView()
- Fragment3 : onAttach()
- Fragment3 : onCreateView()
- ...

My application works very well except if I do the following steps :
1 - open the app
2 - press the home button
3 - force kill the app with builtin optimizer app
4 - open again the app

In this case, the application is :

- Fragment1 : onAttach()
- MainActivity : onCreate()
- Fragment1 :  onCreateView()
- ...

And therefore, the listener I get in the **onAttach()** method is not valid and leads to a NullPointerException when I use the interface ! I don't understand how I can fix it. I have tried to get the callback in the **onCreatedActivity()** but this leads me to other issue.

How can I fix it ?

public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment implements OnNewDataSolcastListener, Animation.AnimationListener, OnFailGetDataSolcast
{

```
private ScaleAnimation mStartingAnimation;
private ViewGroup mBubble;
private Solcast mSolcast;
private TextView mTxtConso;
private TextView mTxtConso2;
private TextView mTxtPresentationConso;
private ImageView mImgErrorSolcast;


@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onAttach()");


    if(getActivity() instanceof Solcast.GetSolcastListener)
        mSolcast = ((Solcast.GetSolcastListener) getActivity()).getSolcast();
    else
        throw new RuntimeException(getClass().getSimpleName() + " have to implement " + Solcast.GetSolcastListener.class.getSimpleName());


}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onCreateView()");

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);


    //init la GUI pour les fonctions qui auront besoin de ces View
    mTxtConso = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtValeurProduction);
    mTxtConso2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtValeurProduction2);
    mTxtPresentationConso = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtPresentationProduction);
    mBubble = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bubbleMain);
    mImgErrorSolcast = rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgErrorSolcast);
    mImgErrorSolcast.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    //some stuff...


    //FAIL HERE : mSolcast null
    mSolcast.setSearchDates(start, end);


    return rootView;
}
```

}

Thank you for your help

**EDIT 1** :

As suggested by Luis Cardoza Bird, I put my code in the onViewCreated(). But I am facing another issue that I quickly mentioned in the original post. I am starting a chain of animations at the end of onViewCreated(). First, at startup, a bubble grows, then a second animation (represented by **mStartingAnimation**) starts while a background thread is downloading a JSON file, and at the end of the last animation, I want to stop the **mStartingAnimation** in the **onNewDataSolcast()** callback. But I get a NullPointerException in this function. I don't understand because I have already started previously, so how it is possible I get a NullPointerException ?
I don't have this problem when I normally open the app.

This is the new code :

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment implements OnNewDataSolcastListener, Animation.AnimationListener, OnFailGetDataSolcast{



private ScaleAnimation mStartingAnimation;
private ViewGroup mBubble;
private Solcast mSolcast;
private TextView mTxtConso;
private TextView mTxtConso2;
private TextView mTxtPresentationConso;
private ImageView mImgErrorSolcast;


@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onAttach()");

}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onCreateView()");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if(getActivity() instanceof Solcast.GetSolcastListener)
        mSolcast = ((Solcast.GetSolcastListener) getActivity()).getSolcast();
    else
        throw new RuntimeException(getClass().getSimpleName() + " have to implement " + Solcast.GetSolcastListener.class.getSimpleName());



    View rootView = getView();
    assert rootView != null;

    //init la GUI pour les fonctions qui auront besoin de ces View
    mTxtConso = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtValeurProduction);
    mTxtConso2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtValeurProduction2);
    mTxtPresentationConso = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtPresentationProduction);
    mBubble = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bubbleMain);
    mImgErrorSolcast = rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgErrorSolcast);
    mImgErrorSolcast.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    //on prépare la future animation pour la bulle qui respire
    mStartingAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1.05f, 1f, 1.05f, 1f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    mStartingAnimation.setDuration(1200);
    mStartingAnimation.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
    mStartingAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);


    //some stuff


    mSolcast.setSearchDates(start, end);


    final ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f, 0, 1f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setAnimationListener(this);
    mBubble.startAnimation(anim);

}

/*
            Appelée lorsque les données JSON ont été reçues puis traitées.
            Renvoi la liste des énergies @listEnergy associées à leur date dans @listeDate
         */
@Override
public void onNewDataSolcast(ArrayList<Solcast.SolcastData> solcastData) {

    //Les données JSON ont été traitées, triées, etc... On renvoi le résultat vers la GUI


    Log.e("ForecastFragment:onNewDataSolcast", "New data");



    //mStartingAnimation is null : NullPointerException here !
    **mStartingAnimation.cancel();**
    mBubble.clearAnimation();



}







//animation callbacks
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    //Lorsque la bulle, au démarrage, a fini de grossir on démarre le téléchargement JSON. Cela peut prendre quelques secondes,
    //donc on fait l'animation de la bulle qui "respire" en boucle jusqu'à réception des données

    //on fait apparaitre le texte "consomation estimée..."
    ObjectAnimator anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTxtPresentationConso, "alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim2.setDuration(2000);

    anim2.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {


            //start animation - works well
            mBubble.startAnimation(mStartingAnimation);


            //will call onNewDataSolcast() callback at the end of the operations
            mSolcast.readJSON();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

        }
    });


    anim2.start();
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
```

}

Comment: attach your crash report too, it will make easy to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the fragment when is the first time being called the onCreate is called, however for solve your issue the best suggestion is to use the onViewCreated, because at that moment the fragment is gonna have the required context already created.

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment implements OnNewDataSolcastListener, Animation.AnimationListener, OnFailGetDataSolcast {

private ScaleAnimation mStartingAnimation;
private ViewGroup mBubble;
private Solcast mSolcast;
private TextView mTxtConso;
private TextView mTxtConso2;
private TextView mTxtPresentationConso;
private ImageView mImgErrorSolcast;    
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onCreateView()");

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);
    //init la GUI pour les fonctions qui auront besoin de ces View    
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public View onViewCreated(){
if(getActivity() instanceof Solcast.GetSolcastListener)
        mSolcast = ((Solcast.GetSolcastListener) getActivity()).getSolcast();
    else
        throw new RuntimeException(getClass().getSimpleName() + " have to implement " + Solcast.GetSolcastListener.class.getSimpleName());    

        mTxtConso = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtValeurProduction);
    mTxtConso2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtValeurProduction2);
    mTxtPresentationConso = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtPresentationProduction);
    mBubble = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bubbleMain);
    mImgErrorSolcast = rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgErrorSolcast);
    mImgErrorSolcast.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    //some stuff...


    //FAIL HERE : mSolcast null
    mSolcast.setSearchDates(start, end);
```

}